# DXA installation: prepare.bat rejects apparently correct Discovery URL

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

When running the prepare.bat script to install DXA 2.2, the validation of the discovery URL appears to fail, as I am faced with the same question again: "What is Discovery URL?".

The URL I am using is `http://cd.local:9082/discovery.svc`. This URL points to a working discovery service.

What might be going wrong? Given that, as far as I can tell, the URL is correct, is there a way to evade the validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in a sub domain. We use apache commons-validators(1.6) for url validation and this library doesn't like "local" subdomain. cd.local:8092 is not valid but cd.com:8092 is.

Answer (score 3):

This one turned out to be easier than I thought. I just used http://www.google.com for the URL and then edited it in the cd_client_conf.xml file once the prepare step was over.